# Run .NET Core App via Console in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

In Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, I run my .NET Core Web API application via console by choosing [AppName] from running profile options on toolbar (Near Little green triangle, dropdown menu) in my previous project. The default options were IIS Express and [AppName], which runs dotnet restore and dotnet run from command prompt.

After I reinstall Windows 10 and therefore VS2015, When I create a new project, I can no longer see default [AppName] option in the dropdown. It has just one option, which is IISExpress.

[image: The dropdown menu for running options]

How can I enable it again? I've also installed dot net core tools for VS2015.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

In Solution Explorer > YourProject > Properties > launchSettings.json,
You should add this to the in `profiles`:

```
"YourProjectName": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
```

And then you can change starting option:

[image]